# Can someone debit cash from my debit card just with an ATR Number?

Tags: credit-card, smartcard

So basically I had a debit card, a built-in smart card reader in my laptop and some money in my account. What I did was, I plugged my debit card in my laptop's smart card reader, I copied the ATR number and (for some complex but foolish reason) shouted my ATR over the Internet.

Can I really be charged by someone knowing my ATR from another country? Or is it just not possible with an ATR?

Answer (score 2):

The [ATR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_reset) is a value output by a smartcard on power-on to tell the reader which communication protocol it supports. Some OSes like Windows also use this value to tell which driver or software to use to handle the card.

The ATR doesn't contain anything confidential and is often the same across a series of cards - there are even [databases](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/smartcard_list.txt) of known ATRs online. **The ATR doesn't contain any information related to the financial aspect of the card.**

Comment: Gee, that really calms me down! So no one can do anything just from an ATR . Thanks !